# React - calling function from a sibling component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Let's say I have a component tree as follows

```
<App>
  </Header>
  <Content>
      <SelectableGroup>
          ...items
      </SelectableGroup>
  </Content>
  <Footer />
</App>
```

Where `SelectableGroup` is able to select/unselect items it contains by mouse. I'm storing the current selection (an array of selected items) in a redux store so all components within my App can read it.

The `Content` component has set a `ref` to the `SelectableGroup` which enables me to clear the selection programatically (calling `clearSelection()`). Something like this:

```
class Content extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.selectableGroupRef = React.createRef();
    }

    clearSelection() {
        this.selectableGroupRef.current.clearSelection();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SelectableGroup ref={this.selectableGroupRef}>
                {items}
            </SelectableGroup>
        );
    }

    ...

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    ...
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Content);
```

I can easily imagine to pass this `clearSelection()` down to `Content`s children. But how, and that is my question, can I call `clearSelection()` from the sibling component `Footer`?

- Should I dispatch an action from `Footer` and set some kind of "request to call clear selection" state to the Redux store? React to this in the `componentDidUpdate()` callback in `Content` and then immediately dispatch another action to reset this "request to call clear selection" state?
- Or is there any preferred way to call functions of siblings?

Comment: does `Select` acts as controlled input? in other words do you set up it as `<Select ... value={valueFromProps}`?

Comment: in React world it's preferred to change props while `ref` is used only if there is no other choice(say to force input to have focus through calling `.focus()`)

Comment: @skyboyer I've changed `Select` to `SelectGroup` - to be clear it's not the HTML Select element. Its a HOC that enables select items by dragging mouse. Using its ref to clear selection is decision made by its creators.

Comment: but you still can wrap it with your own HOC to have `value` and `onChange` props instead of relying on `ref` at every integration point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ref to access the whole functions of Content component like so

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Content ref={instance => { this.content = instance; }} />
        <Footer clear={() => this.content.clearSelection() } />
    
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Content extends Component {
  clearSelection = () => {
    alert('cleared!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Content</h1>
    );
  }
}

class Footer extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Footer <button onClick={() => this.props.clear()}>Clear</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But isn't there something more cleaner? What if I would like to call clearSelection from more components? This way I'm forced to pass the callback to all of them.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do that but I think it's similar to what I did using React but as you are using redux you can save the function inside of the store but doing so can break the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store as well as interfere with time-travel debugging, it's not recommend

Answer (score 2):

I think the context API would come handy in this situation. I started using it a lot for cases where using the global state/redux didn't seem right or when you are passing props down through multiple levels in your component tree.

Working sample:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export const Context = React.createContext()

//***************************//

class Main extends Component {

  callback(fn) {
    fn()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Context.Provider value={{ callback: this.callback }}>
          <Content/>
          <Footer/>
        </Context.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main

//***************************//

class Content extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <Context.Consumer>
        {(value) => (
          <div onClick={() => value.callback(() => console.log('Triggered from content'))}>Content: Click Me</div>
        )}
      </Context.Consumer>
    )
  }
}

//***************************//

class Footer extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <Context.Consumer>
        {(value) => (
          <div onClick={() => value.callback(() => console.log('Triggered from footer'))}>Footer: Click Me</div>
        )}      
      </Context.Consumer>
    )
  }
}

//***************************//
```

Assuming content and footer and in there own files (content.js/footer.js) remember to import Context from main.js

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer of Liam , in **function component** version:

```
export default function App() {
  const a_comp = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <B_called_by_a ref={a_comp} />
      <A_callB
        callB={() => {
          a_comp.current.f();
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const B_called_by_a = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    f() {
      alert("cleared!");
    }
  }));
  return <h1>B. my borther, a, call me</h1>;
});



function A_callB(props) {
  return (
    <div> A I call to my brother B in the button
      <button onClick={() => { console.log(props); props.callB();}}>Clear </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**you can check it in** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-component-call-child-component-function-forked-yze6g9)

Answer (score 1):

One way I use to call the sibling function is to set a new date.
Let me explain more:
In their parent we have a function that set new date in a state (the state's name is something like "refresh date" or "timestamp" or something similar).
And you can pass state to sibling by props and in sibling component you can use useEffect for functional components or componentDidUpdate for class components and check when the date has changed, call your function .

However you can pass the new date in redux and use redux to check the date

```
const Parent = () => {

  const [refreshDate, setRefreshDate] = useState(null);
  
  const componentAClicked = () => setRefreshDate(new Date())

  return (
   <>
     <ComponentA componentAClicked={componentAClicked}/>
     <ComponentB refreshDate={refreshDate}/>
   </>
}
```

---

```
const ComponentA = ({ componentAClicked}) => {
  return (
   <button onClick={componentAClicked}>click to call sibling function!!<button/>
  )
}
```

---

```
const ComponentB = ({ refreshDate }) => {

  useEffect(()=>{
    functionCalledFromComponentA()
  },[refreshDate]

  const functionCalledFromComponentA = () => console.log("function Called")

  return null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Functional components & TypeScript

> **Note 1:** I've swapped `useRef` for `createRef`.

> **Note 2:** You can insert the component's prop type in the second type parameter here: `forwardRef<B_fns, MyPropsType>`. It's confusing because the `props` & `ref` order are reversed.

```
type B_fns = {
  my_fn(): void;
}

export default function App() {
  const a_comp = createRef<B_fns>();

  return (
    <div>
      <B_called_by_a ref={a_comp} />
      <A_callB
        callB={() => {
          a_comp.current?.my_fn();
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const B_called_by_a = forwardRef<B_fns>((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    my_fn() {
      alert("cleared!");
    }
  }));
  return <h1>B. my borther, a, call me</h1>;
});



function A_callB(props) {
  return (
    <div> A I call to my brother B in the button
      <button onClick={() => { console.log(props); props.callB();}}>Clear </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```